# HDF5 filter: How to find out which chunk is written?

Tags: hdf5

I'm trying to compute hash values for HDF5 datasets (e.g. SHA-256) with filters. But unlike in the [filter examples](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.user/Filters.html) I have seen so far, I do not only want to store the hash together with the chunk and check it later.

I plan to mark the chunk as changed on write and use the computed hash later as input to another hash value (thus aggregating a hash for the complete dataset).

Is there a way to see in the filter function which chunk is currently written? The declaration of the callback function would look like

```
size_t my_filter(unsigned int flags, size_t cd_nelmts,
       const unsigned int cd_values[], size_t nbytes,
       size_t *buf_size, void **buf) {
...
}
```

I have the impression that it is only possible to access the raw values and some values that are given when registering the filter.

If yes, is it actually allowed to access (read / write) other datasets from the filter callback function?

Comment: Interesting question.  What does "resp. it hash value" mean?

Comment: Ups, there is a typo: I meant "its hash value" - the hash value of the chunk has changed. I just remove that part of the question, it does not help to understand the problem.